# In a mongodb aggregation pipeline, can I filter an array field with $match?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My objective is to build an aggregation pipeline, that supports both cursor pagination, facets, and search.

I currently have this in the pipeline:

```js
[
  { $search step },
  { $match step },'
  { $facet step},
  {
     $project: {
       category: 1,
       count: { $size: "$docs" },
       docs: 1
     }
  }
]
```

That gives me this results:

```js
{
  category: [{ _id: "categoryA", count: 100 }, { _id: "categoryB", count: 200 } ],
  count: 50,
  docs: [ { _id: ObjectId(), name: "bob" } ... ] // 50 docs
}
```

Is it somehow possible to reduce the docs array, with the $match operator - without loosing my count and category facet information? The output needs to be:

```js
{
  category: // same as above,
  count: 50, (same as above),
  docs: [] // 10 docs - because of pagination
}
```

Our current implementation for cursor-based pagination implements the pagination lock by building a `$match` filter query. It would be awesome to re-use this. Otherwise, I'm afraid my only option is to implement the reducer using [pipe-line operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: Is `docs`  a result of `$facet`? You can use `$match` in the pipeline of `$facet`. Otherwise you can use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), which accepts the same expression as `$match` in `cond` parameter

Comment: Thanks for that wonderful comment  If the `cond` parameter really accepts the same expression as `$match` - my problem is solved. Testing right away ‍♂️

Comment: @TheeSritabtim filtering seems to work  What about sorting an array, is that also possible using one of the pipeline operators?

Comment: From the given pipeline, I guess that `docs` is the output of `$facet`, in that case it's easier to just use `$match` and `$sort` in your `$facet` step. Otherwise, there is no direct way to sort `docs` directly. But if it's just 10 docs and if it's the last step, sorting in your application layer is also possible.

Comment: Point taken. I am trying to solve all the issues in the facet step currently :)

Comment: You have to sort your array in your $facet stage, then use $slice in your project stage. Provide sample docs, it will be easier to help you.